# Drupal Rules - Reference

Tags: drupal, reference, field, drupal-rules

I need to create something like this. Have several nodes ( NODE A ) with: 
C++, PHP, PLSQL, JAVA, etc... ( in each node )

And for, each one of these nodes i will have something like (NODE B): 
1 - medium skills;
2 - good skills;
3 - guru;

I have a reference field in (NODE B) to (NODE A) but i have always to create the same reference data for each node that i create.

Ive tried to use Rules, i did no get to reach to an good solution.

Thankyou all in advance.

PS: this kind of reference has to be like this because i'm using Hierachical Select!

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand the problem: can you provide more info? when you create node B you can reference node A. Are C++, PHP, JAVA taxonomies?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but I think that you may find that you could use a taxonomy instead of node reference. Which would be much easier.

Comment: Well, 

really i do not use taxonomies...

C++, PHP, JAVA are simply nodes.


thank you all